# How to fix 'JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures' in ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm using react router like this.

I get the 'Component' from the routes, but ts throw an error, in the js, there is no Error.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch, useRouteMatch, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import type { MyRoute } from "./types";

const routes: MyRoute[] = [
  {
    path: "overview",
    Component: Index,
    title: "概览",
    name: "index",
    requireAuth: false,
  }
];

const MainRoute: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const match = useRouteMatch();
  const filter = (route: MyRoute): JSX.Element => {
    const { Component } = route;
    return (
      <Route
        key={route.path}
        path={`${match.path}/${route.path}`}
        exact
        render={(props) => {
          document.title = route.title;
          // throw error in this line:JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.
          return <Component {...props} />;
        }}
      />
    );
  };
  return (
        <Switch>{routes.map(filter)}</Switch>);
};

export default withRouter(MainRoute);
```

there is a error:`JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.`
how can I fix it

Comment: Can you share your `MyRoute` type please?

Comment: ```export interface MyRoute {
  path: string;
  Component?: JSX.Element | React.ReactNode | React.FunctionComponent;
  title: string;
  name: string;
  requireAuth?: boolean;
  children?: MyRoute[];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change:

```
  Component?: JSX.Element | React.ReactNode | React.FunctionComponent;
```

to:

```
  Component?: React.FunctionComponent;
```

in `MyRoute` type.

Why? `JSX.Element` it is something like, `<div>jsx element<div>` but your component must be a React component, e. g. function.

Comment: but it also con't fix it

Comment: Can you tell which error it gives you?

Comment: look the new comment

Comment: try this `Component?: React.FC<any>` , also instead of any you can define types of props you use for this component

Comment: [https://github.com/314857493/cra-react-craco](https://github.com/314857493/cra-react-craco)
this is the git repo

Comment: I found the reason of the error. The component can't be undefined...
if I change like `Component:React.FC`, it's fine. But this doesn't match what I'm actually using. When a route has a children, it must not have Component. So the problem is how to do this.

Answer (score -3):

```js
export interface MyRoute {
  path: string;
  Component?: JSX.Element | React.ReactNode | React.FunctionComponent;
  title: string;
  name: string;
  requireAuth?: boolean;
  children?: MyRoute[];
}
```